# How to run a update query in Magento Observer in 1.9.1

Tags: checkout

```
public function placeOrderAfter($evt)
    {
        $order = $evt->getOrder();
        $quote = $evt->getQuote();

        $quote_id = $quote->getId();
        $order_id = $order->getId();

        $collection = Mage::getModel('scancheck/file')->getCollection();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('quote_id',$quote_id);

        Mage::log('Observer Place Order After Quote ID:' . $quote_id);

        foreach($collection as $object){
            Mage::getModel('scancheck/order')->saveFile($order_id,$object->getFilename(),$object->getType());
            $object->delete();
        }
    // I want to run an update query here

}
```

Comment: what query are you want to run?

Answer (score 1):

I saw an alternative solution in this link below:

http://webdesignergeeks.com/cms/magento/how-to-use-select-update-delete-and-insert-queries-in-magento/

> ```
> $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')  
> ->getConnection('core_write');  
> $connection->beginTransaction();  
> $fields = array();  
> $fields['name'] = 'jony';  
> $where = $connection->quoteInto('id =?', '1');  
> $connection->update('tablename', $fields, $where);  
> $connection->commit();
> ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Link became broken. Website doesn't exist anymore... Last snapshot: https://web.archive.org/web/20160503094439/http://webdesignergeeks.com/cms/magento/how-to-use-select-update-delete-and-insert-queries-in-magento/